# How to convert a string format yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

Ive currently got an issue with converting a string field in a ms sql table to my desired date format.

previously i have always used

```
CONVERT(date,c.INP_DATE ,103)
```

but this gives me the error

```
[Err] 22007 - [SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

two sample records i have are 2013-09-18  and 2013-09-18 17:17:32.0000000  which i receive from an import via mysql.  I need these converted to dd/mm/yyyy with time where applicable.

Any help from any gurus out there is appreciated :)

Comment: Why are you storing date data as a string? That's bad! User a datetime. Even with the import, you can still convert and store to datetime at the import point.

Comment: data basically comes from mysql and had problems with date formats previoulsy so easiest way i could think of was to store as string and convert

Comment: anyway the table i am selecting from now has datetime2 as field type and format remains

Comment: The datetime2 data is actually stored in an unreadable binary format. What you see that looks like yyyy-mm-dd is really just the query tool formating the raw data for display.

Comment: Why do you want to present the data in an ambiguous and confusing format like d/m/y? Are you sure your entire audience is and will always be UK/Canadian etc.? Why not use an unambiguous presentation format, like yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: yes its uk only, building an analysis cube so need it this way to avoid date probs encountered in the past

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50) = '2013-09-18'
, @b VARCHAR(50) = '2013-09-18 17:17:32.0000000'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(@a as DATE),103)
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(@b as DATE),103)
```

Comment: ok progress - this works for the date but on the second conversion for the date and time it cuts off the time even when i change it to varchar(19) - any suggestions? tried datetime instead of date and same error as before

Comment: ok think ive sussed it, the 103 seems to crop off the time so i've built it like this and it seems to be fine unless anyone can clean this up a bit  CONVERT(char(10),CAST('2013-09-18 17:17:32' as DATE),103) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST('2013-09-18 17:17:32' as DATETIME), 108)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for CONVERT is

```
CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)
```

where data_type specifies the target data type (with an optional length)
It should be like this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),c.INP_DATE ,103)
```

Comment: yes but this also makes no difference - format still output as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Because you need to convert to date first. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987990/converting-sql-date-formats-not-ending-up-the-same/18989353#18989353

Comment: i was converting date - see question above :)