# How do I convert yymmdd to dd/mm/yy format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and have the column `MyDate` that contains the date as `20141208`. Its type is user-defined (UTypeDate:varchar(8)), and I want to convert it to `08/12/2014`.

For example, given

```
MyDate (UTypeDate:varchar(8))
20141208
20141218
20141204
20141216
```

what I want is to write the query that will give me output as:

```
MyNewDate
08/12/2014
18/12/2014
04/12/2014
16/12/2014
```

How should I write the query for this?

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: yes i have tried Convert(nvarchar(50),MyDate,105) but it is not working

Comment: @user3705817: See [SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: Do you want a copy of  (UTypeDate:varchar(8)) column in the format 08/12/2014 in the result? @user3705817

Comment: i want to convert all the record in column in 08/12/2014 this format that should be in (UTypeDate:varchar(8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987753/convert-string-format-yyyy-mm-dd-to-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST('20141208 ' AS DATE), 103)
```

**RESULT**

[image]

I think you need an extra column on your desired format. Then use the following query.

```
SELECT VARCHARDATE,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(VARCHARDATE AS DATE), 103) NEWDATE
FROM YourTable
```

which forms the below result

[image]

You can apply your logic con `NEWDATE` columns as per your requirements.

Let me know for any changes

Check the sqlfIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af366/1 (Click RUNSQL button when site not loaded properly)

Comment: this works as it is but at 20141208  i want to pass column name  that contains all dates i want to format all column rows to 08/12/2014 this format

Comment: Can you provide more details so that you can more your expecting answers @user3705817

Comment: this is giving me following error (Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.) but i think it works when i continuously execute it. this shows the result but and next sec it show error

Comment: Show you query @user3705817

Comment: SELECT LOT_DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(LOT_DATE AS DATE), 103) NEWDATE FROM MSTGETLOT

Comment: Just check your table design and tell the datatype of LOT_DATE column. @user3705817

Comment: it is my defined type that is  (UTypeDate:varchar(8))

Comment: Are you using Sql server 2008 itself? @user3705817

Comment: There is no way to show the error unless and otherwise you have junk data in your column.
As the datatype is varchar, the column may have 1 or more values which is not in '20141208' format. Check the full table whether you have any junk values, remove it and execute the query. It will definitely work. @user3705817

Comment: Why did you uncheck the marked answer? I had already told you na you have junk data in your table. You accepted that and u told I was right and marked this as the right answer. What happened now? @user3705817

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(MyDate AS DATE), 103) FROM TableName
```

**For visual prrof**

Table Design

[image: Table Design]

Data

[image: Data]

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: yup bdy sry... i was having junk data in my database... thank you